# How to calculate the mean of "n" outputs which I got after using for loop and assign it to a variable?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, mean

I used a for loop to calculate a series of thresholds for diff segments in an image.

```
>>crdf
[(11, 6),
 (11, 7),
 (11, 11),
 (12, 16),
 (10, 9),
 (21, 26),
 (15, 15),
 (12, 17),
 (12, 12),
 (14, 10),
 (20, 26)
]

>>for i in range(0,4):
>>    print(threshold_otsu(img[crdf[i]],16))

-14.606459
-15.792943
-15.547393
-16.170353
```

How to calculate the mean of these thresholds(output values) and store it in a variable using python?

Comment: What have you tried? You've tagged numpy could you try using this library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `modify` your code to look like the following, pay attention to the `for loop` part and `after the for loop`. Essentially all the numbers in the for loop are being appended to an array and to calculate then we calculate the mean of the numbers within that array after the for loop:

```
crdf = [(11, 6),
 (11, 7),
 (11, 11),
 (12, 16),
 (10, 9),
 (21, 26),
 (15, 15),
 (12, 17),
 (12, 12),
 (14, 10),
 (20, 26)
]

arrayOfNumbers=[]

for i in range(0,4):
    arrayOfNumbers.append(threshold_otsu(img[crdf[i]],16))

mean = float(sum(arrayOfNumbers)) / max(len(arrayOfNumbers), 1)
print(mean)
```

I don't know how you calculate thing out with `threshold_otsu()` but eventually if `out of the for loop` you will get those 4 values and they will be appended to `arrayOfNumbers` you will be in a situation like this:

```
#the array will have for example these 4 values
arrayOfNumbers=[-14.606459, -15.792943, -15.547393, -16.170353]


mean = float(sum(arrayOfNumbers)) / max(len(arrayOfNumbers), 1)
print(mean)
#-15.529287
```

Answer (score 1):

Many ways to do this:

**Using numpy:**

```
import numpy as np

thresholds = []
for i in range(0,4):
    thresholds.append(threshold_otsu(img[crdf[i]],16))

mean_threshold = np.mean(thresholds)
```

**Not using numpy:**

```
threshold_sum = 0
i_values = range(0,4)
for i in i_values:
    threshold_sum += threshold_otsu(img[crdf[i]],16)

mean_threshold = threshold_sum / len(i_values)
```